# How to send http post request with an Avro file?

Tags: rest, postman, avro

I have a flask api that is expecting a post request in Avro. The problem is I'm not sure how to send Avro requests to test it. The api reads the data using the fastavro.reader(io.BytesIO(request.data))

I have tried using postman:
In the header defining Content-Type as "avro/binary"
However looks like its not possible 
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4435

I also tried curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: avro/binary" --data "{"city": "ALA",
"number_of_points": 42, "transport": "CAR", "subtype": "PURCHASE"}"
"http://localhost:8080/invocations"
```

However fastavro returns the following error:

File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 725, in fastavro._read.file_reader.**init**

ValueError: cannot read header - is it an avro file?

Resources:

https://github.com/fastavro/fastavro

https://avro.apache.org/

Comment: Have you tried `-H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json"` as per a [reply](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4435#issuecomment-412948601) in that issue thread you linked? EDIT: in fact I read a bit further and someone suggests that won't work for a 'generic avro payload'- worth a try though.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Same error: ValueError: cannot read header - is it an avro file?

Comment: Is the aim actually to upload an `avro` file rather than specifying the payload as the `--data` argument to curl, or equivilant?  Was this `--data` arg just for your example, or is it crucial that you can specify it in this format?

Comment: It was just for the example. That is what my scheme is expecting though. How would I upload an avro file?

Comment: Also, do you have control over the API code... to clarify, I've generated a file with [the fastavro example code](https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example) which results in a file [like this](https://pastebin.com/raw/TNLU35AJ).  Is that what you need to feed the API, if so I have the answer.

Comment: I have control over the API code. Should I do something like 
url = 'http://localhost:8080/invocations' files = {'file': open('out.avro', 'rb')} r = requests.post(url, files=files) ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206162/discussion-between-v25-and-italo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I am assuming you have a valid `.avro` file, as per the [example](https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example) on the fastavro docs.

This then becomes a simple case of handling this as a standard file upload to Flask.  So rather than taking the data from `request.data` you could so something like:

```
from fastavro import reader
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

# This is really basic and could use some validation
@app.route('/invocations', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        for record in reader(file):
                print (record)
        return 'uploaded'
```

You could then submit your file to the endpoint with curl:

```
curl -i -X POST -F 'file=@out.avro' "http://localhost:5000/invocations" -H 'ContentType: multipart/form-data'
```

This should result in something on the server console like:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
{'station': '011990-99999', 'time': 1433269388, 'temp': 0}
{'station': '011990-99999', 'time': 1433270389, 'temp': 22}
```

If you wish to submit using the requests library, you can do something like this:

```
import requests

def upload(filename):
    headers={'ContentType': 'multipart/form-data'}
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        files = {'file': f}
        url='http://localhost:5000/invocations'
        r = requests.post(url, files=files)
        print (r.content, r.status_code)

upload('out.avro')
```

Comment: I think my avro file has a bad format. I'll give you the check anyways. Thanks!!

Comment: @italo No problem, although I'm curious if this works for you eventually so please update :-)